# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined React, state passed to other component is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component, react-state

I have a search bar when the user enters the keyword, I am getting relevant results by making an api call to my backend services by using fetch. I am storing this response from backend in my state. Below is the code for SearchBarComponent:

```
import React from 'react';
import Searchbar from 'material-ui-search-bar';
import Redirect from "react-router-dom/es/Redirect";


class SearchBarComponent extends React.Component{
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        results: [],
        dataFetched: false,
        keyword: 'pre fetch keyword'
    };
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
};

render() {
    if (this.state.dataFetched) {
        return (
            <Redirect to = {{
                pathname: '/results',
                state: {data: this.state.results}

            }}/>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Searchbar
            onChange = {(value) => this.setState({keyword: value})}
            onRequestSearch={() => {
                this.fetchData(this.state.keyword);
            }
            }
        />
    )
}

fetchData (keyword) {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/search?name='+encodeURI(keyword);
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url,{
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()})
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({results: data, dataFetched: !this.state.dataFetched});
        })
}
}

export default SearchBarComponent;
```

After this I want to pass my results to my SearchResultsComponet, so that I could render the results in a google like fashion. This is how I am collecting the passed state into my SearchResultComponent:

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchResultComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: this.props.location.state.data.results
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h4>{this.state.results}</h4>
            </div>
    )}

}

export default SearchResultComponent
```

I am getting error at this line `results: this.props.location.state.data`
I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Any help is much appreciated.
I am handling routing through my index.js file which as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import ResultsPage from './Pages/ResultsPage'
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';



const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path={'/'} component={App}/>
            <Route path={'/results'} component={SearchResultComponent}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I have edited the code, but still I am getting the same error => "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined". In fact, the problem is on the line where I am assigning the state of result component with the passed state of the search component

Comment: try add a console.log in your constructor func of SearchResultComponent. Then can see which part of this.props.location.state.data.results is undefined, so start this.props.location, then try  this.props.location.state, then  this.props.location.state.data, to rule out errors further up component tree or in react router. and check the shape of your data coming from the fetchData api call, it might be different than expected??

Answer (score 0):

When / where are you rendering SearchResultComponent?

'Cannot read property 'state' of undefined' indicates that this.props.location is undefined. Are you sure that at the time this component is rendered you're passing in a location prop that has a value?

Comment: On "/" I am rendering SearchBarComponent. As user enters the keyword in searchbar I am making api call to get results according to that keyword and redirecting my application to "/results" to show the list of fetched results.

Comment: Yeah I double check when I am passing the state to SearchResultComponent I do have the updated value in my state.

Answer (score 0):

Your component SearchResultComponent, has a state initialized in constructor. So, when render is called for the first time in SearchBarComponent, results is setted with an empty this.props.location.state.data (btw you can use props.location.state.data instead). Then after your result fetched, the state of SearchResultComponent is not updated because the component is already mounted, so the constructor is not called, it's on the componentDidUpdate or getDerivatedStateFromProps.

I don't see where you call your SearchResultComponent in SearchBarComponent.

But maybe you can do this :

```js
const SearchResultComponent = props => (
            <div>
                <h4>{props.data}</h4>
            </div>
    )}

}
```

and call your SearchResultComponent like this :

```js
<SearchResultComponent data={this.props.location.data} />
```

Comment: On fetching the result I am redirecting the path to "/results" and there I am rendering "SearchResultComponent". I have added the index.js file where I am handling all the routing.

Also, I tried your solution " (btw you can use props.location.state.data instead)", but this also does not seem to work. What can be done?? I am stuck

Comment: What's the exact error in console plz ?
Or do you have a repo where we can check your code ?